# a program, running on the background (JAVA)

Tags: java, audio, clock

i want to write a clock program, that should run at background and broadcast the current time according to the system if the keys "1" and "2" are pressed together. i already have a program itself (including audiofiles and appendings) so everything i need, is to find the way to make the program window inactive, but to do it in such way that it will activate when the keys are pressed. what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux with KDE you can use khotkeys to set up a keyboard hotkey which will send e.g. a dbus message to your program to tell it to reactivate. I don't know if 1 and 2 together is an allowable hotkey - it doesn't make much sense because it will likely cause a 1 or 2 to be inputted into the program you are currently using, which may or may not do anything but it's better to use a key like ctrl, alt or the windows key to avoid that problem.

In other environments / operating systems there may be something similar to khotkeys, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Java can help you here - you're looking at something like a TSR, which unfortunately is not a Java thing. They went the way of the dinosaurs anyway, along with MSDOS.

You've to go native for something like this on the modern operating systems.

Comment: >You've to go native for that.
excuse me, what does that mean? :)

Comment: Go native means write code in a non-VM language that is not Java. You'd have to consider systems programming.

Comment: I am not a Windows Programmer, but I am sure you can write something to hook into the Windows Keyboard driver, that can let you trap the keystrokes you're interested in. Maybe ask this question in a non-java context and you may have someone reply with more insight.